# When to use sentinel values?

Tags: language-agnostic, sentinel

I recently had to use a GPS location API where each location object had among other things two properties `altitude` and `verticalAccuracy`. A negative `verticalAccuracy` signifies that `altitude` is invalid, whereas normally a smaller but positive value of `verticalAccuracy` actually means that `altitude` is more precise (since it's the vertical distance that it may be off by - I'll leave the discussion as to why this measure is called `verticalAccuracy` and not `verticalInaccuracy` for some other time).

This got me thinking: When is it a good idea to use sentinel values like this API does and when would it be better to explicitly make a separate `hasValidAltitude` property? Are there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, sentinel answers aren't really possible; maybe the function's range coincides with the codomain (range). This isn't the case with altitude, unless you allow negative altitudes (maybe in the future, there will be underwater cities). For instance, maybe we're talking about the intersection between lines (not a great example, since floating-points have a few built-in sentinels like +INF and NaN) or the precise integer quotient (without rounding, this is not guaranteed to exist... 7 and 3, for instance... here, the remainder after division can be viewed as either a sentinel or a "exact integer quotient exists" property). More generally, any reliable sentinel can be trivially used to construct a property-based mechanism.

Based on this, I'd recommend avoiding sentinels wherever this is possible and makes sense. My reasoning is that they are an internal implementation detail of the module, and should be encapsulated behind an information-hiding interface.

Comment: Yeah, and I think Death Valley maybe, too. Hah, still though.